# How do you activate a ruleflow-group in drools

Tags: java, drools, redhat

Can you please help me understand how to fire a specific group of rules in drools 6 final?

I have total of more than 100 rules. I have grouped the rules using ruleflow-group but I don't know how to activate a ruleflow-group. I need to do something like this:

```
if (a == x) fireRuleflowOne
if (a == y) fireRuleFlowTwo
```

I am using StatefulKnowledgeSession and there is nothing in the api that I can use to fire/activate a specific rule group. Before/when calling fireAllRules I want to tell it to fireGroupOfRules.

```
StatefulKnowledgeSession session = knowledgeBase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
session.insert(facts);
session.fireAllRules();
```

Please let me know if you need more detail. thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want to use rule flow groups? Drools 6.x has merged agenda groups and rule flow groups, so setting the focus to an agenda group may be all you need to do.

Comment: What about `ksession.getAgenda().getRuleFlowGroup( "Group C" )` to get the rule flow ? Then probably you can fire all rules it contains. I got it from [the Drools doc](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.3.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html_single/#d0e1898) chapter 4.3.4.3

Answer (score 3):

Though an old thread, someone might bump into this question so here is an example, please note that since it is a part of a Spring Boot project, drools is auto wired!

NOTE: @danidemi was right ofcourse.

```
package com.sample.services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.drools.core.command.impl.GenericCommand;
import org.drools.core.command.impl.KnowledgeCommandContext;
import org.drools.core.common.InternalAgenda;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.kie.api.runtime.ObjectFilter;
import org.kie.api.runtime.rule.FactHandle;
import org.kie.internal.command.Context;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.sample.controllers.CollectResponse;
import com.sample.entities.BusPass;
import com.sample.entities.SalesDroolsProcessParams;
import com.sample.entities.VFactDbDaily;
import com.sample.repositories.VFactDailySalesRepository;

@Service
public class SalesService {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SalesService.class);

    @Autowired
    private KieContainer kieContainer;

    @Autowired
    VFactDailySalesRepository salesRepository;

    public SalesService() {
    }

    public CollectResponse getCollected() {
        Iterable<VFactDbDaily> salesList = salesRepository.findAll();
        ArrayList<Object> collected = new ArrayList<>();

        SalesDroolsProcessParams params = new SalesDroolsProcessParams("yearly");

        KieSession kSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("testKS");

        kSession.setGlobal("log", LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.sample.rules.test"));
        kSession.setGlobal("collected", collected);
        kSession.insert(params);

        ActivateRuleFlowCommand stepOneCmd = new ActivateRuleFlowCommand("step1");

        for (VFactDbDaily fact : salesList) {
            // add the fact to working memory
            kSession.insert(fact);

            // fire all rules
            kSession.fireAllRules();

            kSession.execute(stepOneCmd);
        }

        ActivateRuleFlowCommand stepTwoCmd = new ActivateRuleFlowCommand("step2");

        for (VFactDbDaily fact : salesList) {
            // add the fact to working memory
            kSession.insert(fact);

            // fire all rules
            kSession.fireAllRules();

            // execute ruleflow
            kSession.execute(stepTwoCmd);
        }

        kSession.dispose();

        return new CollectResponse();
    }


    // ruleflow-group implementation
    public class ActivateRuleFlowCommand implements GenericCommand<Object> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private String ruleFlowGroupName;

        public ActivateRuleFlowCommand(String ruleFlowGroupName) {
            this.ruleFlowGroupName = ruleFlowGroupName;
        }

        public Void execute(Context context) {
            KieSession ksession = ((KnowledgeCommandContext) context).getKieSession();
            ((InternalAgenda) ksession.getAgenda()).activateRuleFlowGroup(ruleFlowGroupName);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

HTH